# Kibana: Timestamp field looks different from the Table and JSON fields in the UI

Tags: logstash, timestamp, kibana

[image]

From the combined screenshot can you tell why there is a difference in timestamp for a log entry in different views in Kibana UI.

Update:

My timezone is +5:30 GMT, but I need the logs to show up based on the time in the logfile. The server which sends the log file has the timestamp as BST.

Comment: which is your timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known bug/feature of kibana, it shows timestamp converted to browser local time instead of showing original timestamp (it makes little sense - servers can be all around the world with different timezones but admin sits in one timezone and need to make comparation between events). See https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1600 for more details.